# Which player can play AC3 tracks in a video?

Tags: audio, media-player, ac3

I have a movie in `avi` format and its sound part in `ac3` format. Which player can play my 'custom' sound with a movie?

Answer (score 0):

[Media Player Classic](http://mpc-hc.sourceforge.net/) can let you select different audio tracks:

[image]